# Is this mistake worth reporting

Tags: statistics, notation

In my A level stats exam a question was to show that: $$E(e^{kt})=\frac{1}{1-4k}$$

I took the term $E(e^{kt})$ to mean $E(X)$ where X is crv with a pdf $f(t)$ and $f(t)=e^{kt}, a<x<b$ (and zero otherwise). I then tried to show that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tf(x)dt = \frac{1}{1-4k}$$

Which isnt true.
 In hindsight its clear that the exam board meant to write $E(e^{kT})$ where $T$ is a crv defined in an earlier part of the question whith a cdf $F(t)=1-e^{-0.25t},t>0$. In this case the question would require showing that:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{kt}\frac{d}{dt}F(t)dt = \frac{1}{1-4k}$$

My question is: Is my reasoning correct given the notation of the question and would it be resonable to ask for compensation for the time I wasted trying to prove something that wasnt true?

Comment: Yo mean $f(x)=e^{kx}?$ . $e^{kt}$ has no $x.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, my bad, I have corrected it

Comment: Your interpretation makes far less sense than what was meant in the exam. Indeed they should have used $T$ instead of $t$ if the previously used random variable was $T$, so yes, this should be corrected. But, interpreting this function inside an expectation as a p.d.f. is nonsense; a p.d.f. is not a random variable, it is a function. A function OF a random variable however, is a random variable. You take expectations only of random variables. Besides, there are several equally valid functions that could be used to uniquely define a random variable, so why assume it is a p.d.f.?

Comment: @stanleydodds Thanks, I undersand the disticntion now